# How to clone an object in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, clone, degrafa

I want to clone a Canvas object, which contains a Degrafa Surface with several Geometry shapes.

I tried the naive approach:

```
return ObjectUtil.copy(graph_area) as Canvas;
```

which resulted in errors:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@63b1b51 to com.degrafa.geometry.Geometry.
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@63b1039 to com.degrafa.geometry.Geometry.
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at mx.core::Container/addChildAt()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\Container.as:2196]
    at mx.core::Container/addChild()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\Container.as:2140] ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is called a deep copy, generate a new instance with the same information of the original.

The only way I know how to do it is using ByteArray as follows:

```
private function clone(source:Object):*
{
    var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    buffer.writeObject(source);
    buffer.position = 0;
    return buffer.readObject();
}
```

AS3 is really lacking Object.clone()...

Comment: if you look at the source of ObjectUtil.copy(), it does the exact same thing.

Comment: Yeah, it's using AMF to serialize and de-serialize the object.

Comment: i got error on this code...Error: Error #2030: End of file was encountered.
 at flash.utils::ByteArray/readObject()

Comment: The documentation at
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#copy%28%29
specifically states this function is not intended for UI objects

Answer (score 8):

[ObjectUtil](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html)

The static method *ObjectUtil.copy()* is AS3's "Object.clone()":

```
public static function copy(value:Object):Object
```

> Copies the specified Object and
>   returns a reference to the copy. The
>   copy is made using a native
>   serialization technique. This means
>   that custom serialization will be
>   respected during the copy.
>
> This method is designed for copying
>   data objects, such as elements of a
>   collection. It is not intended for
>   copying a UIComponent object, such as
>   a TextInput control. If you want to
>   create copies of specific UIComponent
>   objects, you can create a subclass of
>   the component and implement a clone()
>   method, or other method to perform the
>   copy.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself trying something more like this alas it still doesn't seem to copy a TextArea (aka UI Object)...

```
public function duplicateObject(sourceObject:*, targetObject:*):void {
    var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    buffer.writeObject(sourceObject);
    buffer.position = 0;
    targetObject = buffer.readObject();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i got the same problem (for a NamedEntity interface i created), looked for the answer here, but only got it working making a call to the registerClassAlias method (which i took from http://richapps.de/?p=34). Just like that:

```
public static function clone(namedEntity:NamedEntity):NamedEntity {
registerClassAlias('test',ReflectionUtil.classByObject(namedEntity));
var returnObject:NamedEntity = ObjectUtil.copy(namedEntity) as NamedEntity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ObjectUtil.copy will work for cloning a canvas. 
According to the flex doc :

Copy 
This method is designed for copying data objects, such as elements of a collection. It is not intended for copying a UIComponent object, such as a TextInput control. If you want to create copies of specific UIComponent objects, you can create a subclass of the component and implement a clone() method, or other method to perform the copy.