# Copying an instance of a class

Tags: apache-flex, class

Ok, ObjectUtil.copy is a good technique for copying Objects. But after having a lot of problems using it to copy other classes, I guess it is not the solution I'm after.

How would you approach the copying/cloning of instances of a class that you've defined? Maybe defining a function withing the class to copy it?

It is cool that most variables are passed by reference in flex, but sometimes is annoying not having control over this (sorry, I'm too used to plain C).

Thanks!

UPDATE:

To be more precise, as I can't make the ObjectUtil.copy() work with a custom class is... is there a way to copy, by using serialization, a custom class? Did you use successfully a ByteArray copy with a custom class?

Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: What classes or objects are you having a hard time copying? Based on your question it sounds like you're trying to copy a custom class you created. Are there objects or properties of your class that aren't being copied correctly? A little more info might help. :)

Comment: Yes, these are custom classes, containing lots of objects and properties. When I use ´var cclassins2:cclass = ObjectUtil.copy(cclassins1) as cclass´ I don't get a copy, but a null. So I guess that that function is just for plain 'Object' classes.

Comment: I believe this to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086436/clone-flex-component and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566066/cloning-object-in-flex-canvas-degrafa-help

Comment: maybe you just lack of `registerClassAlias()`? reference here: https://aheadofthewave.wordpress.com/2007/08/15/type-casting-and-objectutilcopyobj-in-actionscript-30/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the whole class hierarchy, I recommend implementing a `clone()` interface in every class. It's tedious, but will pay off as complexity increases.

(Forgive me if the syntax is a bit off, it's been a while)

```
// define a "cloneable" interface
public interface ICloneable {
  function clone() : Object;
}
```

For every class, implement the method...

```
public class MyClass1 implements ICloneable {
  ...
  public function clone() : Object {
    var copy:MyClass1 = new MyClass1();

    // copy member variables... if it is a user-defined object,
    // make sure you call its clone() function as well.

    return copy;
  }
}
```

To create a copy of the object, simply invoke the `clone()` function.

```
var copy:MyClass1 = original.clone();
```

As a side note, both Java and .NET seem to have adopted the `clone` methods on their base `Object` classes. I know of no analogous method for ActionScript's [`Object`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Object.html) class.

Comment: I agree with zourtney. This would probably be the best solution.

Comment: I indeed considered doing that... but, I wonder, is there a way to copy the whole data block of the instance? (what I understand that it is serialization) It seems more optimal for me, than copying every single variable.

Comment: Another technique I've used is creating an interface which implements `toXML` and `fromXML` functions, but that does not sound beneficial to your scenario either :-/

Comment: See my new answer regarding `ByteArray`. I think it will provide what you're looking for. Good luck!

Comment: The only thing I have to add here is that clone methods are strongly recommended on event classes.  If they don't exist I believe some issues are introduced with bubbling events.

Answer (score 3):

If you determine that implementing a `clone` interface is not the correct approach in your situation, I suggest looking at the [`ByteArray`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) object. I haven't used it myself, but it appears to give you all the control you should need over individual bytes. You can [reading](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readByte%28%29) and [writing](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeByte%28%29) from and to any object.

Senocular does a quick overview of it [here](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showpost.php?s=a04c00363530673a0814b608a95f9295&p=1897368&postcount=77).

```
function clone(source:Object):* {
  var copier:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
  copier.writeObject(source);
  copier.position = 0;
  return(copier.readObject());
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: +1.  This is a common approach, and is almost the same approach used in other answers when this came up.

Comment: Thanks! Funnily, I used that same function sometime in the past (of course, I copy-pasted it). I won't get rid recursively of all of the references this way (classes and objects inside the custom class), but I guess I can combine both methods exposed... (and in the clone function 1st copy the data with this ByteArray method, and correct the data for the child objects by calling their own clone function). Any other method in existence?

Comment: Mmm... the ByteArray method doesn't work... in fact, I think I've tried it before with this class. More on this later :D

Comment: Yep... that's exactly the same code that ObjectUtil.copy() uses. And it gives me a null, as when I used Object.clone() (which has a call to this ByteArray copy and a recursive correction of uid's). I wonder why it is not working with my evil class...

Comment: Hmmm...it doesn't surprise me that `ObjectUtil.copy()` is using that internally. I'm pretty stumped. Can you pinpoint a particular member variable in your class that's tripping up the copying process?

Comment: I don't know, but I couldn't make the ByteArray method work with my custom class, so I ended up using a clone function. Thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 3):

*ObjectUtil.copy* uses *ByteArray* internally to create a copy. In order for the copy to be successful,  ByteArray requires that the flash player will be aware of you custom class. You do that by registering your class using the global **registerClassAlias** method.

For example:

```
//one time globally to the application.
registerClassAlias(getQualifiedClassName(CustomClass), CustomClass); 

//then
var c1:CustomClass = new CustomClass();
c1.name = "customClass";
var c2:CustomClass = ObjectUtil.copy(c1);

trace(ObjectUtil.toString(c1))
trace(ObjectUtil.toString(c2))
```

Comment: I believe OP doenst know he needs to do `registerClassAlias()`, too. A reference here: https://aheadofthewave.wordpress.com/2007/08/15/type-casting-and-objectutilcopyobj-in-actionscript-30/

Answer (score 0):

Two common idioms:

- a `clone` method
- a copy constructor

Both of these let you define what exactly making a copy means--you may want some things copied shallowly and others deeply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I really don't care about the distintion of cloning and copying in this issue. Afaik clone in flex's ObjectUtil preserves the uid, while copy doesn't... I think that doesn't change the question much, which is more related to the approach of instance copying/cloning.

Comment: In any case, take the question as if I was asking about deep copying.